# How to right align dotted line without hspace command?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, ragged2e

The template of my dissertation approval page uses `\hspace` to put a space between each juror's name and its dotted line. How can I right align the dotted lines in output (without using `\hspace`)? Adjusting the whitespaces manually to align the dotted lines looks a little bit challenging.

The following is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fbe}

\begin{document}

%% your title will be written here be careful for the capital letters
\title{ABC}

%% write your name here

%% only first letter of name and surname is capital
%% other letters are lower case

\author{X Y}

%% write your department here
\department{Computer Engineering}

% write your 
\supervisor{Prof. A B\hspace{46mm}........................................}

\cosuperii{Prof. C D\hspace{34mm}........................................}

\examineri{Assoc. Prof. E F\hspace{46mm}........................................}

\examinerii{Assist. Prof. G H\hspace{34mm}........................................}

\dateofapproval{..../..../2019}
%\dateofapproval{Day.Month.Year}

%% use for Ph.D theses  otherwise comment it
\makephdtitle      % For Ph.D. theses

%% uncomment if it is a graduate thesis
% \makemsctitle % For Proposals

\pagenumbering{roman}

\makeapprovalpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\end{document}
```

I couldn't add **fbe** package that I used in my template.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that sets up the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  Also, the solution may be dependent on the packages that you are using.

Comment: @PeterGrill I updated the post and added my MWE.

Comment: Why not use a table to create the desired result?

Comment: @azetina That could work. But I want to use the template as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I updated my MWE. Could you please check?

Comment: @yildizabdullah: Try with something like `\supervisor{\makebox[15em][l]{Prof.\ A B \hfill \makebox[7em]{\hdotfill}}}` where you play around with the values `15em` and `7em`.

Comment: @Werner It didn't work. By the way, it should be `\dotfill` instead of `\hdotfill`, I think.

Comment: @yildizabdullah: Indeed, it should be `\dotfill`. It didn't work? In what way? Did you play around with different (larger) values of `15em`, for example? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Werner Yes, it didn't work. I also tried with larger values.

Comment: You can post `fbe.sty` to [Pastebin](//pastebin.com) and post a link here... Without it, this problem doesn't seem solvable if even the easiest of suggestions don't work.

Comment: @Werner OK. It worked for larger values. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without an indication of what `fbe.sty` looks like, the simplest suggestion would be to place each of the components in a fixed-width box. This allows you to have control over their width as well as spacing:

```
\supervisor{\makebox[20em][l]{Prof.\ A B \hfill          \makebox[7em]{\dotfill}}}

\cosuperii {\makebox[20em][l]{Prof.\ C D \hfill          \makebox[7em]{\dotfill}}}

\examineri {\makebox[20em][l]{Assoc.\ Prof.\ E F \hfill  \makebox[7em]{\dotfill}}}

\examinerii{\makebox[20em][l]{Assist.\ Prof.\ G H \hfill \makebox[7em]{\dotfill}}}
```

In the above example, you need to fiddle with the lengths `20em` (increasing if your names/titles are longer) and `7em` (to change the length of the signature line).